# In Selenium using Ruby, how would I select this updated element's text using xpath?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to select the text inside 'updatedOn_1756', which would typically return something like "10:12 PM". How would I do this? I thought it would be something like element = driver.find_element(:id, "updatedOnID"), but that doesn't work. I'm using Firefox, incidentally.

EDIT: I believe the page is dynamically updated. Though there is no text inside the source shown here, there is a time displayed on the page (it doesn't show in the page source when I click 'view source').

```
        <tr id='row_for_1756'  >
            <td class="IDClass">1756</td>
            <td>Jameson</td>
            <td><a id='DrinkName_1756' class="linkToClient" title="Launch Live Viewer" href='/client/Client.application?myid=1756'>Stevens 18</a> - 
                <a title="BETA Client" href='/client/Client.application?bell=1756' style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">(BETA VERSION)</a> - <a id='DrinkName_Old_1756' class="linkToClient" title="Version before" href='/client/blank/Client.application?myid=1756' style="color: Red;">(old version)</a></td>
            <td>9980</td>
            <td><span id='updatedOn_1756' class="updatedOnID"></span></td>
            <td><span id='histUpdatedOn_1756' class="updatedOnID"></span></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: The text for that element in your example is empty.

Comment: Is there any way I can access it? On the page, as it displays in the browser, there is a time displayed, though it is not visible in page source here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're asking for an `id` with the value `updatedOnID`, which doesn't exist. There is a *class* with that value, but since you're looking for the `id`, you'll need the entire ID value, including the number:

```
driver.find_element(:id, "updatedOn_1756")
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was seeking. For the record, I got the text I wanted using element = driver.find_element(:id, "updatedOn_1756"), puts element.text